# Poisson distribution probability rounding

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-distribution

I'm currently studying for a final and I've hit a roadblock where I can't figure out what the correct way to deal with this is.

Say the number of patrons follows a Poisson distribution: $ X \sim \text{Poi}(10) $. A ticket costs $\$3$, and the person selling the ticket is paid $\$16$ for their work. What is the probability a profit is made?

My attempt:

Let $Y$ be the money made, such that $Y = 3X - 16$. The probability of making a profit is then:
$$ 
\begin{align*}
&=\mathbb{P}(Y > 0) \\
&= \mathbb{P}(3X-16 > 0) \\
&=\mathbb{P}(X > 5.33)
\end{align*}
$$

Since the Poisson distribution is for discrete values only, am I to floor or ceil $5.33$?.

Thanks.

Comment: Because of the discreteness, $P(X > 5.33) = P(X > 5) = P(X \geq 6)$.

Comment: Why do either?  $X$ can be greater than non-integer values as well as integer values!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
5 \times 3 - 16 &= -1 \\
6 \times 3 - 16 &= 2
\end{align}
$$

The enterprise is only profitable if it takes in more money than it spends, so $6$ is the minimum number of tickets that must be sold to be profitable.